# Import large CSV file using fgetcsv in php or Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, csv, fgetcsv

I have problem in importing CSV files with more than 1,00,000 rows. I am using `fgetcsv` for fetching data from CSV file.

My requirement is first truncating table, fetching data from CSV file and stored it in database. But every time it fetchs only 40000 to 50000 rows. Can anyone suggest me what is the issue? My code for that is below,

```
$destination    = realpath('../../admin/webroot/');
$originalPath   = $destination."/".$this->request->data['Importmodel']['importfile'];

# Get Table Fields
$tableFields = ClassRegistry::init('Systemoption')->getTableDetails($this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions']);

ClassRegistry::init($this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions'])->query("TRUNCATE TABLE " . $this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions']);
$row = 1;
if(($handle = fopen($originalPath, "r")) !== false) {
    try {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "|")) !== false) {
            $num = count($data);

            if($num != (count($tableFields) - 1)) { 
                unlink($originalPath);
                $this->Session->setFlash("Table \"".$this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions']."\" fields and \"".$fileName."\" fields does not match", 'default', array('class'=>'flash_bad'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                exit;
            }

            $queryData = array();
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $queryData[$this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions']][$tableFields[$c+1]] = $data[$c];
            }

            ClassRegistry::init($this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions'])->create();
            ClassRegistry::init($this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions'])->save($queryData);
            $row++;
        }
        $result = 1;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = 0;    
    }
}

if($result == 1) {
    unlink($originalPath);
    $this->Session->setFlash("Table \"" . $this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions'] . "\" data populated successfully", 'default', array('class'=>'flash_good'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    exit;
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash("Error : Table \"" . $this->request->data['Importmodel']['modeloptions'] . "\" data not fully populated", 'default', array('class'=>'flash_bad'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If you're importing data from a CSV file into a MySQL table your best option is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. See the [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: What's in the error log? What's your memory and time limit?

Comment: @Mike W : I can't use LOAD DATA INFILE because i need only some columns from CSV. So, i can't use that

Comment: @Maerlyn : I didn't get any error. Memory size is 3000M & time limit is 10000000.

Comment: @Maerlyn : I have checked i got an error     

Caught exception: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound ,     for query : INSERT INTO `vibrantonline`.`hotels` (`hotel_code`, `name`, `category_code`, `destination_code`, `zone_code`, `chain_code`, `license`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES ('163263', 'Balladins Nantes Saint Herblain', '3EST', 'NAN', '6', 'BALLA', '', '47.22954', '-1.6337'),   But i run query direct in phpmyadmin than its working fine. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Set the parameter in core.php to "2" and look at the SQL CakePHP using. This help me alot sometimes. Put the Clause in here maybe

Comment: @hardcoderwithmilestone You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. You have to assign a destination to every field in your input file, but you can assign unwanted fields to dummy variables and discard them. You can also use variables to manipulate the data before assigning it to a column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this from the console? if not, try increasing the memory and time limit in your php.ini